# Can I assign many-to-many relations with ID only?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building a web api with asp.net mvc core and entityframework.

I have two objects with a many-to-many relationship between them.

```
class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Inbox { get; set; }
}

class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

To create a new message, the client sends a JSON to my controller, with the following structure:

```
// POST /api/message
{
    body: "...", // the body and other properties of the message
    recipients: ["user1", "user2"] // a list of the IDs of the recipients of this message
}
```

So basically I need to create a new `Message` object and assign its `Recipients` property based on the user IDs that I received in the JSON.

So far I'm pulling each `User` object from the database to assign it to my `Message`, but this looks like a waste of resources.

```
foreach (var userId in json.recipients)
{
    var userObject = _dbContext.Users.Find(userId);
    message.Recipients.Add(userObject)
}
```

There must be a better way, right? How can I assign the recipients without pulling all that stuff from the database? Or at the very least by doing only one request?

Comment: As a start, try `var userRecipients = _dbContext.Users.Where(user => json.recipients.Contains(user.ID)).ToList();`. Then you should be able to use [AddRange()](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx)

Comment: Isn't this relationship a many-to-many though? A message can have many recipients and a recipient (user) can have many messages.

Comment: Anyway, you could do this: message.Recipients = json.recipients.Select(u => new User { Id = u}).ToList(). The user has to be on the db already. I have a working solution but for a many-to-many relationship which, I think is the appropriate model in your case. Let me know if you want me to post as an answer

Comment: @jpgrassi oh... you’re totally right! Thanks for pointing that out! I edited the question to reflect the change. I’d be very interested to see your solution!

Comment: Added. I used an integer for userId, but shouldn't matter if you have strings. Remembered only after I had the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are working on ASP.NET Core I assumed you are also working with EF Core. The difference is when you have a many-to-many relationship in EF Core you need to create the "linking" entity also on code. In EF6 you didn't need to explicitly have that entity. Anyway, here is what you could do:

Create the linking entity:

```
public class MessageRecipients
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

Configure them:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MessageRecipients>()
    .HasKey(bc => new { bc.UserId, bc.MessageId });

modelBuilder.Entity<MessageRecipients>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.User)
    .WithMany(b => b.Messages)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.UserId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<MessageRecipients>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Message)
    .WithMany(c => c.Recipients)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.MessageId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Then in your `POST` message you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostMessage([FromBody] MessageViewModel viewModel)
{
    var message = new Message
    {
        MessageBody = viewModel.MessageBody,
        Recipients = viewModel.Users.Select(c => new MessageRecipients { UserId = c}).ToList()
    };

    _context.Messages.Add(message);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}

public class MessageViewModel
{
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This will populate the many-to-many table accordingly:

[image]